# Getting route conflicts when trying to group routes

Tags: sveltekit

Here is my file structure:

[image]

My goal is :

- Have a `(public)` part where anyone can have access
- Have a `(private)` part where only logged-in users have access.

To achieve that, I made a `(private)/+server.ts` file, that is supposed to check if the user is logged in.

But when I do that, I get this error:

```
3:37:48 PM [vite] page reload src/routes/(private)/+server.ts
The "/" and "/(private)" routes conflict with each other
The "/" and "/(private)" routes conflict with each other
```

If I remove the `/+page.svelte` it works fine, but I cannot access the `/` route any more.

What would be the correct approach to achieve what I want?